# How to remove items from ArrayList by fields from another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 ArrayList:

```
List<ExcludedCalls> excludedCalls = ExcludedCallJpaDao.me().getExcludedCalls();
List<Calls> callsForSend = CallJpaDao.me().getCallsForSend();

public class ExcludedCalls  {
    private long id;
    private String callingNum;
...
}
```

and

```
public class Calls {
    private long id;
    private Date date;
    private Integer secdur;
    private String condcode;
    private String dialednum;
    private String callingnum;
    private Operators operators;
    private Integer status;
    private PollMessage pollMessage;
...
}
```

I need to delete all items from callsForSend where `callingnum` contains in `excludedCalls`

I tried this:

```
public List<Calls> getCallsForSend() {
        List<ExcludedCalls> excludedCalls = ExcludedCallJpaDao.me().getExcludedCalls();
        List<Calls> callsForSend = CallJpaDao.me().getCallsForSend();
        List<Calls> ex = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Calls call : callsForSend) {
            if (excludedCalls.contains(call.getCallingnum())) {
                ex.add(call);
            }
        }
        callsForSend.removeAll(ex);
        return callsForSend;
    }
```

But I know that this is wrong. Lists has different objects. I can form `Set` from `excludedCalls` but I don't want many foreach.

Comment: *I need to delete all items from callsForSend where callingnum contains in excludedCalls*. Sorry but this is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use an `Iterator<T>` with nested looping. compare the `callingNum` from the respective objects and remove if equal.

```
Iterator<ExcludedCalls> excludedCallsIterator = excludedCalls.iterator();
Iterator<Calls> callsIterator = callsForSend.iterator();

while (callsIterator.hasNext()) {
  Calls calls = callsIterator.next();
  while (excludedCallsIterator.hasNext()) {
    ExcludedCalls excludedCalls1 = excludedCallsIterator.next();
    if (calls.getCallingnum().equals(excludedCalls1.getCallingNum())) {
      callsIterator.remove();  // remove the object from callsForSend if it matches the current excludedCalls's callingNum.
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a good solution, but you can not do without the double cycle?

Comment: You can store all the `callingNum` into a `Set<String>` and then compare. But check it does not break anything in the logic. Even here also we are comparing `callingNum` and removing them.

Answer (score 0):

n java8 you can use filter on stream
ex:-

```
calls.stream().filter(call->!exclude.contains(call.getCallingnum())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java ArrayList the `contains()` function does a linear search O(n) through the list to find a match by calling each objects `equals()` function.

If you can change implementation such that the objects share a common interface, e.g. `ICall`, you can use this approach:

```
public List<Calls> getCallsForSend() {
    List<ExcludedCalls> excludedCalls = ExcludedCallJpaDao.me().getExcludedCalls();
    List<Calls> callsForSend = CallJpaDao.me().getCallsForSend();
    callsForSend.removeAll(excludedCalls);
    return callsForSend; 
}
```

If you can't change the implementation, then performing the iteration yourself is the simplest approach:

```
public List<Calls> getCallsForSend() {
    List<ExcludedCalls> excludedCalls = ExcludedCallJpaDao.me().getExcludedCalls();
    List<Calls> callsForSend = CallJpaDao.me().getCallsForSend();
    Iterator<ExcludedCalls> excludedCallsIterator = excludedCalls.iterator();
    Iterator<Calls> callsIterator = callsForSend.iterator();

    while (callsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Calls calls = callsIterator.next();
        while (excludedCallsIterator.hasNext()) {
            ExcludedCalls excludedCalls = excludedCallsIterator.next();
            if (excludedCalls.getCallingNum().equals(calls.getCallingnum())) {
                callsIterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return callsForSend;
}
```

If space isn't an issue you could add the Calls to a HashMap and then remove the ones that exist in the excluded calls list:

```
public List<Calls> getCallsForSend() {
    List<ExcludedCalls> excludedCalls = ExcludedCallJpaDao.me().getExcludedCalls();
    List<Calls> callsForSend = CallJpaDao.me().getCallsForSend();
    Map<String, Calls> callsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Calls call : callsForSend) {
        callsMap.put(call.getCallingnum(), call);
    }

    for (ExcludedCalls excludedCall : excludedCalls) {
        callsMap.remove(excludedCall.getCallingNum());
    }

    return new ArrayList(callsMap.values());
}
```